# Once I have devise installed, how do I add (and remove) modules easily? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just added `:confirmable` but am now getting an error:

```
NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x000001025db288>
```

I realized that after I added it, I didn't do anything that would generate a migration.

How do I get a new migration to alter the current schema on an existing devise install?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783392/how-do-i-enable-confirmable-in-devise

Comment: @RadBrad that's just for `confirmable`. I am interested in all modules...not just `confirmable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Here's Devise wiki page on how to change existing table to suit Devise needs:

For Devise below 2.0

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns

For Devise after 2.0

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Comment: No I know how to create a migration. But with Devise, I don't know the exact names of the columns that are needed. This question is specific to devise's modules....not to rails db migrations ;)

Comment: Btw, I tried that and am now getting this error in during my `migrate`: `undefined method lconfirmable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x000001021ec6e0>`

Comment: The same wiki page explains this. Since 2.0 there are no more migration helpers. Check the new update.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783392/how-do-i-enable-confirmable-in-devise).

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the best way to do this is via this [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style) link.

I just tested it and it seems to work.