# Devise Confirmable token not routing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have managed to install devise into my rails application. The email generates and the email is sent to the user. My trouble is that when I click on the link to confirm my registration I get the following error in my google chrome browser

```
> `Oops! Google Chrome could not find http`
> http://http//localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=HCJ5yqnWkiESnVxcbeqe
```

It seems though that the following `link_to` is not working correctly:

`<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>`.

My devise confirmable set up followed the following SO question [How do I enable :confirmable in Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783392/how-do-i-enable-confirmable-in-devise)

I am also using the latest version of devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `config/environments/development.rb` file and make sure that it's set up as follows:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

From the URL you posted it seems as though you've configured the host as `http//localhost:3000`

Comment: I realised that my error was that I put `:host => 'http://localhost:3000' }` which meant that inside the browser it was doing `:host => 'http:http://localhost:3000' }

Comment: What funny is that I only realised this after I pasted the url. X_X note to anyone else DO NOT put `http:` before. Rails automatically detects this¬