# undefined method `confirmable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, data-migration, devise-confirmable

I am getting the following error when rake db:migrate is run:

```
undefined method `confirmable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x6d448e8>
c:/java/RubyProjects/myproject/db/migrate/20111202225103_make_user_confirmable.rb:4:in `block in change'
c:/java/RubyProjects/myproject/db/migrate/20111202225103_make_user_confirmable.rb:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  ...

end
```

20111202225103_make_user_confirmable.rb:

```
class MakeUserConfirmable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      t.confirmable
    end

    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
  end
end
```

Not sure what else is to be done..

Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Doing `devise :confirmable` in your `User` model adds the Devise "confirmable" *module* to your User *model*, it doesn't add a *method* to your *table*.

Comment: See this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783392/how-do-i-enable-confirmable-in-devise][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783392/how-do-i-enable-confirmable-in-devise

Answer (score 3):

**edited:**
[How To: Add :confirmable to Users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users)

P.S.
There's no [such type](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types) as `confirmable` in rails migrations, so the migration fails.
But if you still want to add `confirmable` column to user table:

```
class MakeUserConfirmable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      t.boolean :confirmable, :default => false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: They are using Devise, this.. is a thing.